my post to firestore batch (from cloud run service) is timing out no matter what is the size of my batch
I'm trying to accomplish what seems like a straightforward task: reading CSV files from a Cloud Storage bucket and pushing the rows into Firestore in batches. I've set the batch size to 500 and also experimented with smaller sizes like 100, but the operation keeps timing out. I consistently get errors such as
4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded after 192.136s
Both my Google Cloud Run service and Firestore are in the same region, so latency shouldn't be an issue. Single document writes (insert/update) are working perfectly, but when I try to process and upload a full CSV file to Firestore in batches, I hit these errors.
I am new to cloud dev so I am pretty sure I m doing something wrong. What am I doing wrong?
Has anyone encountered this before, and how did you resolve it? Are there specific optimizations or configurations I should try to make this work?"
Here is my code. Key function that sends batch to Firestore is writeBatchToFirestore
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const { Firestore } = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const csvParser = require("csv-parser");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

let firestoreConfig = {
  projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
  databaseName: `MASKED-firestore-db`,
};

// If running in development mode, use the Firestore emulator
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "DEV" && process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST) {
  firestoreConfig = {
    ...firestoreConfig,
    host: process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST,
    ssl: false,
  };
}

// Firestore configuration
const firestore = new Firestore(firestoreConfig);
const contactsCollection = firestore.collection("contacts");
const listCollection = firestore.collection("lists");
const FIRESTORE_BATCH_SIZE = 250;

// Google Cloud Storage
const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = process.env.BUCKET_NAME || "MASKED-sftp-bucket";

app.post("/importlist", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.query;

  if (!id) return res.status(400).json({ error: "id is required" });

  try {
    const docRef = listCollection.doc(id);
    const docSnapshot = await docRef.get();

    if (!docSnapshot.exists) return res.status(404).send("List not found");

    const listData = docSnapshot.data();
    const { companyId, divisionId, objectId, contactTypeColumn, name } = listData;

    const filePath = `${process.env.BUCKET_PORTAL_UPLOAD_PATH}/${companyId}/${divisionId}/${objectId}`;
    const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filePath);

    res.status(200).send({ message: `Started processing list ${name}` });
    await processFileInBackground(file, id, docRef, contactTypeColumn);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error importing file:", err);
    res.status(500).send({ error: `Failed to start file import for id ${id}` });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});

// Process file in batches and write directly to Firestore
async function processFileInBackground(file, listId, docRef, contactTypeColumn) {
  const batch = [];
  const contactTypeCounts = {};
  const listData = (await docRef.get()).data();
  const doNotImportColumns =
    listData.doNotImportColumns?.split(",").map((col) => col.trim()) || [];

  console.log(`Starting list ${listId} import`);
  console.log(new Date().toString());

  const stream = file.createReadStream().pipe(
    csvParser({
      mapHeaders: ({ header }) => toValidJsVariableNameAsync(header),
    })
  );

  stream.on("data", async (row) => {
    row.listId = listId;

    // Exclude columns in doNotImportColumns
    const filteredRow = filterRow(row, doNotImportColumns);

    const contactType = filteredRow[contactTypeColumn];
    if (contactType) {
      if (["sms", "email", "voice"].includes(contactType)) {
        contactTypeCounts[contactType] =
          (contactTypeCounts[contactType] || 0) + 1;
      } else {
        contactTypeCounts.invalid =
          (contactTypeCounts.invalid || 0) + 1;
      }
    }

    batch.push(filteredRow);

    // Write batch to Firestore if it reaches the size limit
    if (batch.length === FIRESTORE_BATCH_SIZE) {
      await writeBatchToFirestore(batch.splice(0, FIRESTORE_BATCH_SIZE));
    }
  });

  stream.on("end", async () => {
    // Write remaining rows in the last batch
    if (batch.length > 0) {
      await writeBatchToFirestore(batch);
    }

    // Update Firestore document with contact type counts and status
    await docRef.update({
      contactTypeCounts,
      status: "COMPLETED",
    });

    console.log(`File processing completed for listId: ${listId}`);
    console.log(new Date().toString());
  });

  stream.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Error processing file:", err);
  });
}

// Write a batch of data to Firestore
async function writeBatchToFirestore(batch) {
  const firestoreBatch = firestore.batch();
  batch.forEach((row) => {
    const docRef = contactsCollection.doc(); // Auto-generate document ID
    firestoreBatch.set(docRef, row);
  });

  await firestoreBatch.commit();
  console.log(`Committed a batch of ${batch.length} records to Firestore`);
}

// Convert headers to valid JavaScript variable names
function toValidJsVariableNameAsync(str) {
  let validName = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g, "_");
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z_]/.test(validName)) validName = "_" + validName;
  return validName;
}

// Filter out columns specified in doNotImportColumns
function filterRow(row, doNotImportColumns) {
  const filteredRow = { ...row };
  doNotImportColumns.forEach((column) => {
    delete filteredRow[column];
  });
  return filteredRow;
}


I have tried different batch sizes, tried throttling also but nothing worked

Please update your question to include a minimal repro of your issue (not just code snippets). What exactly (!) are you doing that receives the deadline exceeded? What is the full log entry of the deadline exceeded? Specifically which service is throwing the error? Cloud Run defaults to 5 minutes (request timeouts) and, since 192s is less than 300s, it's not evidently Cloud Run that's producing the error. Batch processing tasks like this may be better suited to Cloud Run jobs.
